# Steps to reduce time delay due to GC allocation failure in azure databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm, azure-databricks

I'm executing a print "Hello World" Job in azure databricks python notebook on a spark cluster. Every time the Job is run it takes more than 12 seconds to execute which is expected to take less than 12 secs as it's the simplest python code anyone can think of. When I verify the logs it shows GC Allocation failure as follows:

```
2019-02-15T15:47:27.551+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 312512K->57563K(390144K)] 498744K->243803K(1409024K), 0.0153696 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-02-15T15:47:28.703+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 206668K->65267K(385024K)] 392909K->251515K(1403904K), 0.0187692 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-02-15T15:47:28.722+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 65267K->0K(385024K)] [ParOldGen: 186248K->244119K(1018880K)] 251515K->244119K(1403904K), [Metaspace: 110436K->110307K(1144832K)], 0.3198827 secs] [Times: user=0.64 sys=0.04, real=0.32 secs]
```

Wanted to know is the Job delay > 12 secs due to GC allocation failure? If yes, how can I reduce it? If not, what can be the other reason for the delay and how to correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an overhead of starting a Spark Job on a cluster. If processing petabytes then the overhead is small but here it is noticable. The GC is not an issue here.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there a way to reduce this overhead?

Comment: No, just the nature of Spark.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Also, do you know anyway to way to reuse the spark context? As per my understanding, every time a job is executed on Spark it creates a spark context which eventually adds up to the start time of a Job.

Comment: I am not familiar with that environment but with spark-shell no issues when doing 2 prinlns. May be there is a setting, see https://data-flair.training/blogs/learn-apache-spark-sparkcontext/ and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/pyspark_sparkcontext.htm, or consult the software manual. I am not sure what mode it operates in, but if submitting to cluster then you will get an overhead as I stated. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links, will look into them. Though I still don't get what is the real difference between running a "Hello World" program through a databricks notebook directly which takes just 0.06 secs to run whereas the same notebook when triggered through a databricks job takes so long to run(>12 secs).

Comment: Yes, it is interesting as the spark-shell has no issue, but I suspect that you are submitting to the cluster every time, that is an overhead every time.

Comment: GC is not the issue, I hope you see that, and that that part of the question is answered.